# How could I count item based on each index by using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing people's information ordered by index. For example, my dataframe looks like below.

```
#df
Name  A  B  C  D  E  F
John  1  0 -1 -1 -1  1
Lisa  0  1 -1  2  0  2
Mary  1  2  2  0  2  0
```

I'd like to count each people in different categories'(that is A, B, C, D..) performance. Then I can see something like below in the result.

```
#print result
     -1 0 1 2 
John  3 1 2 0
Lisa  1 2 1 2
Mary  0 2 1 3     

#which means John got 3 times in -1, 1 time in 0, 2 times in 1, and 0 times in 2. 
#A, B, C, D...etc does not matter to result.
```

At the first step I used `df.T` to transpose the dataframe, and tried something like `df.value_counts()`, however I'd 
like to count them based on each person rather than using `df.stack().value_counts()`. And it seems not achieveable by `groupby()` function,

Does anyone know how to get it by using pandas in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it could be more elegant, but you can do:

```
>>> df.set_index('Name')
        .groupby(level=0)
        .apply(lambda x: x.stack().value_counts())
        .unstack()
        .fillna(0)
```

Detailed:

```
>>> df.set_index('Name')
>>> 
      A  B  C  D  E  F
Name                  
John  1  0 -1 -1 -1  1
Lisa  0  1 -1  2  0  2
Mary  1  2  2  0  2  0

>>> df.set_index('Name')
      .groupby(level=0)
      .apply(lambda x: x.stack().value_counts())
>>>
Name    
John  -1    3
       1    2
       0    1
Lisa   2    2
       0    2
      -1    1
       1    1
Mary   2    3
       0    2
       1    1

>>> df.set_index('Name')
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda x: x.stack().value_counts())
    .unstack()
    .fillna(0)
>>>
          -1   0   1   2
Name                
John   3   1   2   0
Lisa   1   2   1   2
Mary   0   2   1   3
```

Comment: Appreciated, I have tested it and it works!!! Now I am going to check the meaning of function in pandas documentation. :)